# Cannot use Heroku CLI without sudo, get 'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: macos, heroku, heroku-cli

After installing the CLI, I'm unable to run any heroku commands without using `sudo`. attempting to do so results in this error:

```
user at iMac in ~
> heroku [[anything]]
 ▸    autoupdate:: 'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
 ▸    '/Users/user/Library/Caches/heroku/update.lock.readers.lock'
 ▸    'EACCES': EACCES: permission denied, mkdir
 ▸    '/Users/user/.local/share/heroku'
```

I've tried changing ownership and permissions in those directories to the current user/group and set permissions as high as 777, but the error remains. I've uninstalled (while verifying successful uninstall) and reinstalled the heroku CLI manually, through homebrew, and with npm--but no change. I'm a bit out of ideas.

Running heroku-cli/6.14.36 (darwin-x64) node-v8.7.0 (via nvm) on macOS High Sierra 10.12.6.